# phpMyAdmin can't connect to mysql when using Docker-Compose, it works using "docker run"

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin

I am currently trying to configure a new server running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

There is one application running outside docker: My nginx reverse proxy / webserver. This should not interfere because it only listens on port 80 and 443. Accessing the PMA Interface works fine.

Currently there are 3 Docker Containers running: a PHP-FPM Container (which handle php processing coming from nginx), MySQL and phpMyAdmin.
All 3 of them are created by docker-compose, the .yml file looks as follows:

```
version: "3"
services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: /srv/docker/dockerfiles/php-fpm
    image: php-fpm:latest
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - "/srv/docker/volumes/php-fpm/config/:/usr/local/etc/php/"
      - "/srv/docker/volumes/php-fpm/ssh/:/root/.ssh/"
      - "/srv/www/:/srv/www/"
      - "/srv/docker/volumes/php-fpm/logs/:/var/log/php-fpm/"
    restart: unless-stopped

  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<insert secure password>
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=sintra01
    volumes:
      - "/srv/docker/volumes/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql"
    restart: unless-stopped

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8443:443
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=sintra01
      - PMA_PORT=3306
    volumes:
      - "/srv/docker/volumes/phpmyadmin/config/:/etc/phpmyadmin/"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

(please ignore the masses of volumes, I know this is bad)

Now, this does not work. When clicking on login in the PMA login form, the following error message appears:
`#2002 - No such file or directory &mdash; The server is not responding` and `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory`

Running the PMA Container manually by using
`sudo docker run --name myadmin -d -e PMA_HOST=sintra01 -p 8080:80 -p 8443:443 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin`

it works perfectly.
I can also connect to the DB by using e.g. MySQL Workbench, regardless of using compose or docker run. So I guess the culprit has to be docker-compose in some way.

EDIT: OK, I apparently it also affects the php container. I cannot connect to the database from any php script.